# What should I do if I post a discussion instead of a question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: *[Is Laravel 8 with jQuery an old technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237067/is-laravel-8-with-jquery-and-old-technologie)*

Sorry. In my post, I think that I have permission to ask this kind of question, but in comments I understood that was not a question, but a discussion. What should I do? Should I remove the post or close it or what?

Comment: We've closed it for you. You can delete it or if not the system will likely delete it for you eventually. It's not really salvageable I'm afraid. It might be best if you checked out [the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before asking any more questions.

Comment: Open-ended discussions aren't on-topic here. Use reddit, quora, or some other site instead

Comment: It's more of an opinionated question really. Laravel 8 definitely is not old since 8.x is the current release tree so you are essentially asking if JQuery is old. You can definitely google things like "why not to use JQuery" - happy reading, see you in a couple of days.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I would suggest going to their help center before offering up that site as an alternative. From their on-topic page: "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here."

Comment: I suggest installing or enabling a spell checker in your browser. For tech words, you can use [Edit Overflow](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=JQuery).

Comment: OK. Thanks to all of you.